# Error message when integrating the Tappx SDK

Tags: objective-c, integration

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/michaelnares/Desktop/TripMatcherNew/TappxFramework.framework/TappxFramework, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x58 0x53 0x79 0x6D 0x0A 0x30 0x30 0x33 0x31 0x0A 0x62 0x66 0x35 0x65 0x33 0x38 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/michaelnares/Desktop/TripMatcherNew/TappxFramework.framework/TappxFramework
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TappxFramework", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

I have this problem when trying to integrate the Tappx SDK for promotion of one of my iOS apps.  Is it possible to solve this without having access to the Tappx framework source code?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the static library was built only for ARM architecture but you are trying to build your app on the simulator, which runs on x86_64.
I suppose the Library documentation can point you out how to only import it when building for physical devices

Comment: I've just tried to build the app on an actual iPhone, and this hasn't made any difference.

Comment: What is the error message when you try to build on the iphone? I doubt it complains about x86_64

Comment: It's the exact same one.

Comment: Please be sure you are building on an iPhone and that your target is correctly set, because x86_64 is the architecture of your Mac: it should say ARMV(something)

Comment: Where can I find that within XCode, please?

Comment: I am not sure, I'd take a look for something smelly in the build settings of the target you're trying to build